# Accessing a class variable within inner class variable assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to use a class variable as part of the definition of another one within the same class as follows:

```
import enum, struct

class Message:
    """ExtendedIO related message IDs and `Struct.struct`s."""

    # protocol
    BYTE_ORDER = "<"

    # Message ID's
    class ID(enum.IntEnum):
        """Message ID's definitions."""
        EX_IO = 0x01
        ALIVE = 0x02
        RESETCOMPONENT = 0x03

    STRUCTS = {
        ID[message_id]: struct.Struct(
            ''.join((BYTE_ORDER, format)))
        for message_id, format in {
            'EX_IO': "B",          # command
            'ALIVE': "HH",         # version, version
            'RESETCOMPONENT': ""}  #
        .items()}
```

This gives a `NameError: name 'BYTE_ORDER' is not defined`.

I can do:

```
import enum, struct

class Message:
    """ExtendedIO related message IDs and `Struct.struct`s."""

    # protocol
    BYTE_ORDER = "<"

    # Message ID's
    class ID(enum.IntEnum):
        """Message ID's definitions."""
        EX_IO = 0x01
        ALIVE = 0x02
        RESETCOMPONENT = 0x03

class Message(Message):

    STRUCTS = {
        Message.ID[message_id]: struct.Struct(
            ''.join((Message.BYTE_ORDER, format)))
        for message_id, format in {
            'EX_IO': "B",          # command, *
            'ALIVE': "HH",         # version, version
            'RESETCOMPONENT': ""}  #
        .items()}
```

And it works, but the extra `class Message(Message):` looks ugly and pylint complains with an [E0102](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:e0102).

The benefit of the way `Message.STRUCT` is assigned is that it uses a very readable table. (The actual code I am working on is a bit more complex.)

Based on the comments, I tried the following code, which works:

```
import enum, struct

class Message:
    """ExtendedIO related LWF message IDs and `Struct.struct`s."""

    # protocol
    BYTE_ORDER = "<"

    # Message ID's
    class ID(enum.IntEnum):
        """Message ID's definitions."""
        EX_IO = 0x01
        ALIVE = 0x02
        RESETCOMPONENT = 0x03

    EXAMPLE = ''.join((BYTE_ORDER, '1'))

    STRUCTS = lambda ID, BYTE_ORDER: {
        ID[message_id]: struct.Struct(
            ''.join((BYTE_ORDER, format)))
        for message_id, format in {
            'EX_IO': "B",          # command
            'ALIVE': "HH",         # version, version
            'RESETCOMPONENT': ""}  #
        .items()}(ID, BYTE_ORDER)
```

So:

- Directly using a class variable works.
- Inserting the variables into the comprehension using a `lambda` also works.
- Using the extra `class Message(Message):` works.
  (and `importlib.reload()` works on the first code example, but the result is wrong...)

Is there a sane way of using a class variable within another class variable in the same class in Python?

Comment: This do not broke your code? class Message(Message): you are extending one class and declaring with the same name

Comment: If you already extendeds the main class the variable should be available to you

Comment: @DiegoVinícius `class Message(Message) is perfectly legal - even if an obvious smell...

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem. Maybe this is not the best structure for what you are trying to accomplish. Do you really need this *inner class* to be indeed an inner class], for starters?

Comment: The problem is actually with using BYTE_ORDER in a list comprehension or dict comprehension - it works fine else.

Comment: @RafaelC There are more `STRUCTS`, `pack`, `unpack`, etc around. This gives me an inheritable namespace to keep a few sets of similar 'things'.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Indeed. Just doing something like `EXAMPLE = ''.join((BYTE_ORDER, '1'))` actually works. Now it smells a little bit like a little bug.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the explanation. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the way you make use of the variables being *class* instead of *instance* variables, you could also change an existing class variable in your constructor. This way, your variable is still a class variable shared by all instances of the class.

```
class Message:
    BYTE_ORDER = "<"
    STRUCTS = {}

    def __init__(self):
        STRUCTS = self.SomethingDependantOn(self.BYTE_ORDER)
```

You would not be able to access the variable without instantiating an object first though.

Comment: I thought of that myself. I would like these constants to be available before I ever instantiate something, if possible. I do not actually have instances of all variants, but the constants are used nevertheless.

Comment: From my point of view, dependant class variables do not really make sense as that's what instance variables are used for. Nevertheless, the INSANE solution would of course be entering the value of BYTE_ORDER manually but I am quite confident you would like to avoid that ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can access this variable using **self**

```
class Message:
    """ExtendedIO related message IDs and `Struct.struct`s."""

    # protocol
    BYTE_ORDER = "<"

    # Message ID's
    class ID(self, enum.IntEnum):
        """Message ID's definitions."""
        EX_IO = 0x01
        ALIVE = 0x02
        RESETCOMPONENT = 0x03

    def something(self):
        STRUCTS = {
            ID[message_id]: struct.Struct(
                ''.join((self.BYTE_ORDER, format)))
            for message_id, format in {
                'EX_IO': "B",          # command
                'ALIVE': "HH",         # version, version
                'RESETCOMPONENT': ""}  #
            .items()}
```

or just set your varible global and access it by your classes

```
# protocol
BYTE_ORDER = "<"

class foo():
    def something():
        print(BYTE_ORDER)

class bar():
     def something():
        print(BYTE_ORDER)
```

Comment: The first option should be the correct solution to the question.

Comment: The first option results in `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: @KeesValkhof fixed the error, the struct should be inside a function that receive self as parameter